# HTML tables within tab widgets are not converted correctly into HTML

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets, nbconvert

I am having problem with nbconvert where resulting HTML tables do not render correctly if the tables are within tab widget. My notebook is as follows:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, Markdown, display
import ipywidgets as widgets

table = "<table><tr><th>Sample</th></tr><tr><td>Text</td></tr></table>"

display(Markdown("# Name"))
display(HTML(table))

tabs = []

tab = widgets.Output()
with tab:
    display(Markdown("# Name1"))
    display(HTML(table))
    tabs.append(tab)

tab2 = widgets.Output()
with tab2:
    display(Markdown("# Name2"))
    display(HTML(table))
    tabs.append(tab2)

all_tabs = widgets.Tab(children=tabs)
for i, name in enumerate(["1", "2"]):
    all_tabs.set_title(i, name)
display(all_tabs)
```

When running the above with `jupyter nbconvert --execute sample.ipynb --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True --output-dir=C:\Users\sample\Downloads\ --to html --output sample.html`.

It shows that the tables render correctly in the top part of the page but tables do not render correctly inside of the tab widget. Is this is bug or a user error?

I am running in a clean virtual environment with following packages:

```
GitPython
matplotlib
numpy
pandas
pyquaternion
scipy
jupyter
```

Which results into following detailed list of packages:

```
anyio                    3.6.2
argon2-cffi              21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings     21.2.0
arrow                    1.2.3
asttokens                2.2.1
attrs                    22.2.0
backcall                 0.2.0
beautifulsoup4           4.11.2
bleach                   6.0.0
build                    0.10.0
cffi                     1.15.1
click                    8.1.3
colorama                 0.4.6
comm                     0.1.2
contourpy                1.0.7
cycler                   0.11.0
debugpy                  1.6.6
decorator                5.1.1
defusedxml               0.7.1
executing                1.2.0
fastjsonschema           2.16.2
fonttools                4.38.0
fqdn                     1.5.1
gitdb                    4.0.10
GitPython                3.1.31
idna                     3.4
ipykernel                6.21.2
ipython                  8.10.0
ipython-genutils         0.2.0
ipywidgets               8.0.4
isoduration              20.11.0
jedi                     0.18.2
Jinja2                   3.1.2
jsonpointer              2.3
jsonschema               4.17.3
jupyter_client           8.0.3
jupyter-console          6.6.1
jupyter_core             5.2.0
jupyter-events           0.6.3
jupyter_server           2.3.0
jupyter_server_terminals 0.4.4
jupyterlab-pygments      0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets       3.0.5
kiwisolver               1.4.4
MarkupSafe               2.1.2
matplotlib               3.7.0
matplotlib-inline        0.1.6
mistune                  2.0.5
nbclassic                0.5.2
nbclient                 0.7.2
nbconvert                7.2.9
nbformat                 5.7.3
nest-asyncio             1.5.6
notebook                 6.5.2
notebook_shim            0.2.2
numpy                    1.24.2
packaging                23.0
pandas                   1.5.3
pandocfilters            1.5.0
parso                    0.8.3
pickleshare              0.7.5
Pillow                   9.4.0
pip                      22.3.1
pip-tools                6.12.2
platformdirs             3.0.0
prometheus-client        0.16.0
prompt-toolkit           3.0.37
psutil                   5.9.4
pure-eval                0.2.2
pycparser                2.21
Pygments                 2.14.0
pyparsing                3.0.9
pyproject_hooks          1.0.0
pyquaternion             0.9.9
pyrsistent               0.19.3
python-dateutil          2.8.2
python-json-logger       2.0.7
pytz                     2022.7.1
pywin32                  305
pywinpty                 2.0.10
PyYAML                   6.0
pyzmq                    25.0.0
qtconsole                5.4.0
QtPy                     2.3.0
rfc3339-validator        0.1.4
rfc3986-validator        0.1.1
scipy                    1.10.1
Send2Trash               1.8.0
setuptools               65.5.0
six                      1.16.0
smmap                    5.0.0
sniffio                  1.3.0
soupsieve                2.4
stack-data               0.6.2
terminado                0.17.1
tinycss2                 1.2.1
tomli                    2.0.1
tornado                  6.2
traitlets                5.9.0
uri-template             1.2.0
wcwidth                  0.2.6
webcolors                1.12
webencodings             0.5.1
websocket-client         1.5.1
wheel                    0.38.4
widgetsnbextension       4.0.5
```

Comment: I figure out that the problem is that HTML entity characters in generated tab widgets seem to prevent page to be rendered correctly. A fix that works for me is to read in the generated html and replace all `&gt;` with `>` and all `&lt;` with `<`, and then write the write this as a new HTML.